# How to pass clicks and touch events through a region in a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

how can pass clicks and touch events through only a part of UIView?

The thing is that I have UIScrollView with transparent first element working as a spacing from the top and then I put some another views. I want that first element to pass clicks and touches to underlying views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hitTest` to pass the touch events to view below.

Create a subclass of `UIScrollView` and override the `hitTest`

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var underlyingViewReference : UIView!

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if underlyingViewReference.frame.contains(point) {
            return underlyingViewReference
        }
        else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above `underlyingViewReference` is the view to which you would like to handover the touch to.

If you dont wanna pass the reference of the view you can always declare protocol in UIScrollView and viewController loading UIScrollView can confirm to that protocol and later return the view as a return value :)

Hope it helps

Comment: I had to call return underlyingViewReference!.hitTest(point,with: event), however your answer helped a lot. Thank you

Comment: @szymon-klimaszewski : Am glad it worked :) Happy coding